# Partitioning tables in PostgreSQL by a value stored in a different table

Tags: postgresql

We are using a partitioning scheme that uses a date field in the table to determine the partition that should be used i.e. table *foo* with child *foo_y2016m01*.

This works for our simpler tables, but we are researching how to approach some of our more complex table relations to do the same style of partitioning, such as *foo* having a date field and *bar* storing the row id of the associated record in *foo*.  The *bar* table does not have a date field of its own, but we still want to partition the table such that child tables would follow the same format (*bar_y2016m01*).

Is it possible to format the check constraint on *bar* such that it can use the date field from *foo*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Possibly.

You can use an expression in check constraint so you can write a function that will check the other table for you. However it will be only triggered during instert/update on the table so the data might loose integrity and you'll have to use a foreign key or add a trigger to table `bar` to keep `foo` correct.

Comment: My working prototype for doing this: https://gist.github.com/smbarbour/1bf9745d7b1bce48c3b4